# R rmarkdown::render() looses js dependencies of DT::datatable()

Tags: r, r-markdown

#### The problem

I am trying to use `rmarkdown::render` function to generate a standalone html report with tables formated using `DT::datatable` function. I seem to loose JavaScript dependencies using this approach if I output the report to other directory than the working one.

On the other hand, everything works fine if I press the `Knit` button in RStudio. Report is generated, tables are formated as expected. I can send the report via email. I can copy the report using `ctrl + c` and paste it wherever using `ctrl + v`. It just works. However, it does not work for me if I copy the `.html` report to other folder using `file.copy`.

#### What I tried

I looked at and read [Howto include js dependencies of DT datatable in Rmarkdown using knitr and pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303827/howto-include-js-dependencies-of-dt-datatable-in-rmarkdown-using-knitr-and-pando), I also tried to understand [knit DT::datatable without pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645528/knit-dtdatatable-without-pandoc). I stil cannot get it to work.

As always, there must be some simple option I am missing. Could you help please.

#### Session Info

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] printr_0.0.4   DT_0.1         markdown_0.7.7 rmarkdown_0.8  knitr_1.11     dplyr_0.4.3    stringr_1.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1   R6_2.1.1         jsonlite_0.9.16  DBI_0.3.1        formatR_1.2      magrittr_1.5    
 [9] evaluate_0.7.2   highr_0.5        stringi_0.5-5    lazyeval_0.1.10  rstudioapi_0.3.1 tools_3.2.0      htmlwidgets_0.5  yaml_2.1.13     
[17] parallel_3.2.0   htmltools_0.2.6
```